# Picture shrinks down in size, but doesn't grow back?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to make an image shrink down in width, change the image source, and grow back out. It shrinks, but it doesn't grow back. Any ideas what's wrong?

```
while (pictureBox2.Size.Width > 0)
{
    int width = pictureBox2.Size.Width;
    width -= 2;
    pictureBox2.Size = new Size(width, pictureBox2.Size.Height);
    pictureBox2.Location = new Point(pictureBox2.Location.X + 1, pictureBox2.Location.Y);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
}
pictureBox1.Image = currentImage;
while (pictureBox2.Size.Width < 191)
{
    int width = pictureBox2.Size.Width;
    width += 2;
    pictureBox2.Size = new Size(width, pictureBox2.Size.Height);
    pictureBox2.Location = new Point(pictureBox2.Location.X - 1, pictureBox2.Location.Y);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: any reason for `pictureBox1.Image = currentImage;`

Comment: @EmrahSüngü that's a _different_ `PictureBox`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your drawing problems are due to not allowing Windows to paint your controls properly.  Typically Windows controls receive a `WM_PAINT` or equivalent when processing the message pump.  If apps don't process this pump (because say they are busy in a `while` loop sleeping) then generally no updates occur.

If you want to do it in a `while` loop then you arguably should use `pictureBox2.Refresh()` instead of calling `Thread.Sleep()`.   The former will block the current thread (the UI thread) and allow the picture box to repaint itself.  The latter only serves to block the current thread which is probably why you are not seeing updates.

MSDN

> Forces the control to invalidate its client area and immediately redraw itself and any child controls.  [Tell me more...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh(v=vs.110).aspx)

In practice, you may want to investigate into using a *timer* instead of a tight loop and sleeping.

Answer (score 0):

Mark your method with `async`, then use `await Task.Delay(1);` instead of `Sleep()`.  This will keep the app responsive and allow the UI to actually repaint itself as the size of your PictureBox changes:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    while (pictureBox2.Size.Width > 0)
    {
        int width = pictureBox2.Size.Width;
        width -= 2;
        pictureBox2.Size = new Size(width, pictureBox2.Size.Height);
        pictureBox2.Location = new Point(pictureBox2.Location.X + 1, pictureBox2.Location.Y);
        await Task.Delay(1);
    }
    pictureBox1.Image = currentImage;
    while (pictureBox2.Size.Width < 191)
    {
        int width = pictureBox2.Size.Width;
        width += 2;
        pictureBox2.Size = new Size(width, pictureBox2.Size.Height);
        pictureBox2.Location = new Point(pictureBox2.Location.X - 1, pictureBox2.Location.Y);
        await Task.Delay(1);
    }
}
```